# Wordpress title for category+tag

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

this url

wp-themes.com/?cat=1&tag=boat

will show all posts under category "1" and tag "Boat"

but in the title only the name of the category is shown

How to show both category and tag?

Answer (score 0):

You can place this in your functions.php file and format the title whenever both a tag and category is added.

```
function title_tag_and_category( $title, $id = null ) {

    if ( isset( $_GET['cat'] ) &&  isset( $_GET['tag'] ) {
        //UPDATE TO HOW YOU WANT THE PAGE TITLE TO BE FORMATTED
        return 'Category: ' . get_cat_name( $_GET['cat'] ) . ' and Tag: ' . get_term_by('name', $_GET['tag'], 'post_tag');
    }

    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'title_tag_and_category', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: It should be $_GET

Comment: @Fencer04 `the_title` did not update the title but `pre_get_document_title` did

Comment: @Fencer04 the code still cannot get the tag and cat names it shows "Category: and Tag: "

Comment: @Ahmen Let's see if the query string is being read correctly.Try replacing the return line with: return 'Category: ' . $_GET['cat'] . ' and Tag: ' .  $_GET['tag'];